# How to start Django up programmatically

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have a Django app (for example, `myapp`) and a Python script (let us say, `myscript.py`) both in the same directory. How could I start (and stop) the Django app from the script? Is there an object or function for this? Or should I use the `subprocess` trick?

Comment: What do you mean “start the app”? Run the built-in simple server?

Comment: @DavidWolever exactly, I want to run the built-in server.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`django.core.management.call_command`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django.core.management.call_command).

For example:

```
from django.core import management
management.call_command('runserver')
```